# Can we execute a method before the JSF Validator is triggered?

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2.2

Is it possible to execute any java bean method before the JSF Validator for all the components in a page can execute ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `<f:event>` to hook on the [`PreValidateEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/PreValidateEvent.html) as below:

```
<h:form>
    <f:event type="preValidate" listener="#{bean.preValidate}" />
    ...
</h:form>
```

```
public void preValidate(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can we restrict this 'PreValidateEvent' event to fire on click of any button in the sampe page ?

Comment: Only if you use ajax. If true, simply nest it in the command button of interest and make sure that other buttons don't cover that button in `<f:ajax execute>`. An alternative is to use a normal validator and check in its `disabled` attribute if the button's client ID is present in request parameter map.

Comment: Is this your speaking about ? <h:commandButton...> <f:event type="preValidate" listener="#{bean.preValidate}" /> </h:commandButton>  and what is the alternative approach ? I didnt understand it completely.

Comment: Press "Ask Question" button if you have new questions unrelated to the main Question in its current form. I'm tempted to just delete the answer if you keep chameleonizing the question in answer's comments.